# Insert a date depending on the value of other cell in same row

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a task manager. I have five columns: `Category`, `Date`, `Description`, `Status` and `End date`.

What I want is to do is to fulfill the `End date` automatically if the value of the cell `Status` is "completed".

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The example is an easy model of the spreadsheet that I have. Scripting is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rodo,

Fill in the sheet name (the name of the 'tab', NOT the name of the spreadsheet)  in var sheetName and see if this works:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheetName = 'YOUR_SHEETNAME_HERE';
var editCol = 4;
if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== sheetName || e.range.columnStart !== editCol || e.range.rowStart < 2) return;
e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(e.value === 'Completed' ? new Date() : null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is working. I am going to try to understand the code you give me because I can do a lot of things with this in my spreadsheet.

Comment: @G.Rodo. If this helps, please mark my answer. The if-statement checks the current sheet name (should be the same as var sheetName) and the currently edited column (should be 4). If one of these conditions is not true, the scripts exits. Else it places a timestamp in the adjacent column ( -->offset(0, 1) when the value 'Completed' is entered. If the edited value is not 'Completed' (or empty) timestamp will be erased.

Comment: Really good code. I got impressed when I changed the value of the State Column  when it was Completed previously and the timestamp disapeared. I modified your code to suit on my really spreadsheet... Is it possible to set many triggers at the same time to try to do the same thing but with other cells?

Comment: @G.Rodo: If you want to use the script on other cells (when the same/another column is edited) you'll have to add this to the current code. If you need help with that, please specify what you want to achieve with the code.